# Alguna forma cambiar indices de array?

Tags: php, array

me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de separar un array por una parte del texto y utilizar eso como índice del mismo.

```php
array('Nombre: Empresa1', 'Direccion: Empresa1', 'Tlf: Empresa1');
```

Que viene siendo:

```php
Array ( [0] => Nombre: Empresa1 [1] =>  Empresa1 [2] =>  Empresa1 )
```

Y quiero cambiarlo por:

```php
Array ( [Nombre:] => Empresa1 [Direccion:] => Empresa1 [CIF:] => Empresa1 )
```

Estuve probando con implode/explode y preg_split... pero no soy capaz de logralo.

Seguramente esto sea una tontería y necesite tomar clases más profundas de PHP... pero en eso estoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías recorrer el Array aplicando un explode a cada elemento y generar un nuevo Array,  por ejemplo:

```
<?php
// valores
$a = array('Nombre: Empresa1', 'Direccion: Empresa1', 'Tlf: Empresa1');
// inicializamos un nuevo array
$data = array();

foreach ($a as $v) {
    // cortas el elemento por los dos puntos (':')
    $e = explode(':', $v);
    // asignas el primer valor del explode como key y el segundo como valor 
    $data[$e[0]] = $e[1];
}
print_r($data);
```

Resultado:

```
 Array (
     [Nombre] => Empresa1
     [Direccion] => Empresa1
     [Tlf] => Empresa1 
 )
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfecto. Es justo lo que necesitaba e intentaba hacer, pero me estaba confundiendo al asignar las keys.